# BroadcastReceiver no detecta cuando Inicia el dispositivo ni inicia la aplicación en automático en un Xiaomi

Tags: java, android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto que me pasaron y que ya contenía un broadcaste receiver el cuál probé con Toast para revisar que funcionara, en el emulador de android studio funcionó sin problemas sin embargo al probarlo en mi celular físico, un Xiaomi Redmi note 8 no parecía arrancar. Mi aplicación debía detectar cuando arrancara el dispositivo y entonces luego de un minuto debía arrancar la aplicación también, sin embargo no parecía funcionar en el Xiaomi.

Este es mi código:

```
public class AppReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static boolean isRegister;

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i("AppReceiver","--AppReceiver.onReceive..");
    try {
        switch (Objects.requireNonNull(intent.getAction())) {
            
            case Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED:
                runApp(context);
                break;
            
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("AppReceiver/catch", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void runApp(Context context){
    try {
        new Thread(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(60000);
                            Intent init = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
                            init.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            context.startActivity(init);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
        ).start();

    } catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(context, "AppReceiver/runApp/catch: "+e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

Mi código del Manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.AppReceiver"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
            <!--For HTC devices-->
            <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Llevas más de 5 años en el sitio, ya deberías saber que en la pregunta debe ir exclusivamente el problema y en la respuesta la solución. Lo que debes hacer es una pregunta auto-respondida. Básicamente **mueve la parte de la solución a una respuesta**. Esto no es un foro ni un blog.

Comment: Creo que has hecho una investigación valiosa. No dejes que se pierda esta información. Como dice el otro comentario, separa la respuesta.

Comment: En realidad no es solo tener Xiaomi, se debe a los dispositivos que tienen MIUI que últimamente son todos los nuevos dispositivos Xiaomi como Redmi.

Answer (score 1):

Investigando un poco me di cuenta que Xiaomi tenía en su capa de seguridad la configuración de bloquear las aplicaciones que se iniciaban en automático, por lo cuál tuve que buscar dicha característica en la configuración del equipo y dentro buscar mi aplicación para habilitarla manualmente. Habilitando esto se solucionaba la detección cuando se encendia la app, pero aún faltaba hacer que se iniciara la aplicación móvil.

Para arrancar la app tuve entrar en la configuración del equipo, entrar en la lista de aplicaciones y buscar mi app. Dentro de la configuración de la app busqué la sección de "Otros permisos", dentro de esta sección habilité el permiso "Mostrar ventanas emergentes mientras se ejecuta en segundo plano" y fue todo.

Espero que esto les pueda ayudar a quienes tengan problemas similares con esta marca y los broadcast receivers.

Answer (score 0):

No deberías tener ningún problema al usar BOOT_COMPLETED y [detectar el inicio de tu dispositivo](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-start-app-on-BOOT_COMPLETED).

El problema en algunos teléfonos que tienen instalado MIUI de Xiaomi (Redmi), que es una capa de personalización, no define de forma predeterminada a las aplicaciones el permiso de inicio automático (Autostart), en este caso debes activar el permiso.

Puedes activar el permiso de la siguiente forma:

Debes revisar en Settings > Apps > Manage apps > Selecciona la aplicación y habilita "Autostart"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si tienes instalado MIUI puedes ir directamente a "Security" > "Manage apps" > Selecciona la aplicación y habilita "Autostart"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]